# Use the output of a stored procedure inside a while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to assign the output of a stored procedure (which is @@ROWCOUNT) to a variable. Then I would like to use this variable in the conditional statement of a WHILE loop. How can I make it to work. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @Row INT
SET @Row = EXECUTE @Row = [Model].[RemoveOutlier] @VId = 15, @Pass = 1, @StDev = 1 
WHILE @Row > 0
    EXECUTE @Row = [Model].[RemoveOutlier] @VId = 15, @Pass = 1, @StDev = 1
```

I would like to execute the [Model].[RemoveOutlier] proc until @Row (or the returned `@@ROWCOUNT` by the proc itself) is higher than 0.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That procedure code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: The *real* question is why do you want to use a `WHILE` loop? SQL is a set based language.

Comment: You could use an `OUTPUT` parameter. But really, it's unlikely this code is even necessary, as @Larnu has pointed out, but cannot advise unless we can see the code for the procedure

Comment: So what is stopping you from examining `@Row` and then breaking the loop if needed? You will need more than one statement - so you need a block for your WHILE loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is the  procedure [Model].[RemoveOutlier]  change the database?
YES: Consider to use use other procedure with transaction with rollback but return the @row simulating the commit.

NO:Consider other procedure only return @row without affecting data or something, because you not sure what value will return.

I need more information about your problem to help you.